# Откуда эта ошибка, когда конвертирую из string в int в C#?

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Откуда эта ошибка, когда конвертирую из string в int в C#?

Comment: Код конвертации покажите. И данные посмотрите в отладчике

Comment: что именно непонятно в строке: _Входная строка имела неверный формат_?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Эта ошибка возникает, если строка не содержит число. Чтобы "мягко" преобразовывать строку в число, используйте метод `TryParse()`:

```
int number;
bool result = int.TryParse("42", out number); // true

int number2;
bool result2 = int.TryParse("ololo42", out number2); // false
```

Comment: скорее всего там `.` вместо `,` или наоборот в числе.

Comment: @Grundy в int'e нет разделителя )

Comment: @Trymount, еще одна причина ошибки :)

Answer (score 1):

*Входная строка имела неверный формат* - означает, что Вы пытаетесь преобразовать строку символов в целое число, при этом в исходной строке символов не все символы являются числами. Для того, чтобы выяснить, что пошло не так - достаточно просто посмотреть, что Вы передаете в метод преобразования. К примеру:

```
string inputStr = "123a56";
int number;
bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(inputStr, out number);
if(isNumeric)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Строка успешно преобразована в число");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ошибка преобразования. Вы уверены, что '" + inputStr + "' число?");
}
```

Ошибка, связанная с `DateTime` возможно падает, потому что входная строка составного формата. Этот составной формат построен неправильно и похож на дату. И Вам правильно сказали использовать [Метод Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx).

Полезные ссылки для ознакомления:

1. [FormatException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.formatexception(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. [Составное форматирование](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. Метод, используемый Вами [Метод Int32.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) (скорее всего)

Если Вы хотите использовать именно `Int32.Parse`, то проблему можно решить так:

```
string inputStr = "123a56";
try
{
    int number = Int32.Parse(inputStr);
    Console.WriteLine("Строка успешно преобразована в число");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ошибка преобразования. Вы уверены, что '" + inputStr + "' число?");
}
```

Про операторы `try-catch` можно почитать тут:

1. [try-catch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0yd65esw.aspx)
2. [try-catch-finally](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dszsf989.aspx)